# Declaration or statement expected on subscribe() for ts 3.0.1

Tags: angular, typescript, subscription

I am getting declaration or statement expected. I have recently updated ts and angular.

```
getTopics() {
    this._dataService.getTopics().subscribe(res => {
        this.topics = res;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.topics.length; i++) {
            if (this.topics[i]._id > this.max) {
                (this.max = this.topics[i]._id);
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my bad. i was missing a }. but it was working in previous version.

```
getTopics() {
this._dataService.getTopics().subscribe(res => {
    this.topics = res;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.topics.length; i++) {
        if (this.topics[i]._id > this.max) {
            (this.max = this.topics[i]._id);
        }
    }
});
}
```